# How to implement a deterministic, formula based lookup?

Tags: lookup

I have the need to implement a lookup towards an SObject, but instead of an hard-wired relationship I need it to be implemented as a formula. I have a discrete number of instances of the target SObject, and I can compute given the source SObject in a very simple way, which of the instances of the target SObject I should looking up to.

Are the best practices to implement a deterministic, formula based lookup?

Comment: Does this change depending on values changing in the source SObject? This sounds like something that you would just do from the trigger on insert/updates to the source SObject, but not sure if I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for.

Comment: Why go for a formula here? What benefit does it provide over a custom relationship field?  Depending on what you want to do with this formula-based relationship, you're comitting yourself to a lot of extra work (e.g. want to display your field as a clickable link that shows the parent record name? That'll probably need a trigger and an extra field)

Comment: NB: Formula fields cannot be of type Lookup. The best you would have is an ID as a string, but you can't use standard Salesforce UI functionality to show it as a lookup and would have to deal with this all yourself.